# play configuration for securesocial

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1, securesocial

I want to support only facebook in securesocial 2.0.12 for play 2.1.0, so I've deleted other providers from securesocial.conf. My applications doesn't start right now, I'm getting following error:

```
    Cannot load plugin
    An exception occurred during Plugin [securesocial.core.providers.LinkedInProvider]    initialization
    No source available, here is the exception stack trace:
        ->java.lang.RuntimeException: [securesocial] Missing properties for provider            'linkedin'. Verify your configuration file is properly set.
    securesocial.core.IdentityProvider.throwMissingPropertiesException(IdentityProvider.scala:136)
    securesocial.core.OAuth1Provider.createServiceInfo(OAuth1Provider.scala:50)
    securesocial.core.OAuth1Provider.<init>(OAuth1Provider.scala:33)
    securesocial.core.providers.LinkedInProvider.<init>(LinkedInProvider.scala:29)
```

My play.pluging file looks like this after I removed all the unwanted providers(only facebook is needed)

```
 1500:com.typesafe.plugin.CommonsMailerPlugin
 9994:securesocial.core.DefaultAuthenticatorStore
 9995:securesocial.core.DefaultIdGenerator
 9996:securesocial.core.providers.utils.DefaultPasswordValidator
 9997:securesocial.controllers.DefaultTemplatesPlugin
 9998:service.InMemoryUserService
 9999:securesocial.core.providers.utils.BCryptPasswordHasher
 10001:securesocial.core.providers.FacebookProvider
 10004:securesocial.core.providers.UsernamePasswordProvider>
```

Is it correct? I am using play 2.1.0 with securesocial 2.0.12

Comment: How were you specifying your configuration files? `play -Dconfig.file=conf/yourotherconfigifnotapplication.conf run`

Answer (score 0):

If you are following their wiki on how to get started, its not detailed.
Open up a demo example that they have provided and try to replicate that.
It should work.